# Keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynini' in Pycharm and Spyder

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, spyder, pynini

I recently installed `pynini` using "conda install -c conda-forge pynini". It seems to have been installed since I checked with conda list and it was there. However, when I tried it out through PyCharm or Spyder (both with Python Interpreter to be Anaconda3), I kept getting:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynini'

despite having installed it. I don't know where I went wrong here so any insights or help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Which conda environment did you install?
`conda install -c conda-forge pynini` will install on the current active environment.

On PyCharm, check which conda environment you are on.

Comment: I installed miniconda3 and when I checked, it showed "Requirement already satisfied: pynini in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython>=0.29 in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pynini) (0.29.21)". But on PyCharm, I think I'm on anaconda3 instead and I don't know how to change from that to miniconda3.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be "PATH" problem. You should check PATH or env.
OR... remove and install conda environment.